# The call stack in console contains unreadable character

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The following call stack is copied from code console. `s4Link22getPersistentContainerSo012NSPersistentD0CyF` contains some unreadable character like `s4`, `22`. Does it can be replaced with original path?

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread:
> -[UIApplication delegate] PID: 5202, TID: 471753, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x7fd76fc0f2d0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0
> Backtrace: 4   Link                                0x000000010d0d4f13
> $s4Link22getPersistentContainerSo012NSPersistentD0CyF + 67 5   Link
> 0x000000010d0370dd $s4Link10DataSourceCACycfc + 29 6   Link
> 0x000000010d036fd1 $s4Link10DataSourceCACycfC + 33 7   Link
> 0x000000010d0ca419
> $s4Link10DomainDataCACycfc7Combine12AnyPublisherVyytAA13ResponseErrorVGycfU1_
>
> - 105 8   Link                                0x000000010d0ca560 $s7Combine12AnyPublisherVyyt4Link13ResponseErrorVGIego_ytAGIegnr_TR +
>   16 9   Link                                0x000000010d0ca5b1
>   $s7Combine12AnyPublisherVyyt4Link13ResponseErrorVGIego_ytAGIegnr_TRTA
> - 17 10  Combine                             0x00007fff235ad683 $s7Combine10PublishersO7FlatMapV5Outer33_E91C3F00A6DFAAFEA2009FAF507AE039LLC7receiveyAA11SubscribersO6DemandV6OutputQy_F
> - 131 11  Combine                             0x00007fff235af170 $s7Combine10PublishersO7FlatMapV5Outer33_E91C3F00A6DFAAFEA2009FAF507AE039LLCy_xq__qd__GAA10SubscriberA2aJP7receiveyAA11SubscribersO6DemandV5InputQzFTW + 16 12  Combine                             0x00007fff235ac641 $s7Combine10PublishersO7FlatMapV5Outer33_E91C3F00A6DFAAFEA2009FAF507AE039LLC12receiveInneryAA11SubscribersO6DemandV6OutputQz_SitF
> - 241 13  Combine                             0x00007fff235ac544 $s7Combine10PublishersO7FlatMapV5Outer33_E91C3F00A6DFAAFEA2009FAF507AE039LLC4SideV7receiveyAA11SubscribersO6DemandV6OutputQzF
> - 20 14  Combine                             0x00007fff23590b60 $s7Combine10PublishersO3MapV5Inner33_5A6CD15A64659A6248DAF677D4BB6188LLV7receiveyAA11SubscribersO6DemandV6OutputQzF
> - 144 15  Combine                             0x00007fff235913b1 $s7Combine10PublishersO6TryMapV5Inner33_5A6CD15A64659A6248DAF677D4BB6188LLC7receiveyAA11SubscribersO6DemandV6OutputQzF
> - 305 16  Combine                             0x00007fff23591940 $s7Combine10PublishersO6TryMapV5Inner33_5A6CD15A64659A6248DAF677D4BB6188LLCy_xq__qd__GAA10SubscriberA2aJP7receiveyAA11SubscribersO6DemandV5InputQzFTW + 16 17  Combine                             0x00007fff23585da3 $s7Combine10PublishersO12HandleEventsV5Inner33_9464E9048FC4C9C669F954B681B5AD45LLC7receiveyAA11SubscribersO6DemandV6OutputQzF
> - 243 18  Combine                             0x00007fff23586060 $s7Combine10PublishersO12HandleEventsV5Inner33_9464E9048FC4C9C669F954B681B5AD45LLCy_x_qd__GAA10SubscriberA2aJP7receiveyAA11SubscribersO6DemandV5InputQzFTW
> - 16 19  libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x00007fff5158d9b4 $sSo12NSURLSessionC10FoundationE17DataTaskPublisherV5Inner33_1AA038E5228015E36E90CFE2C93D33C4LLC14handleResponse4data8response5erroryAC0C0VSg_So13NSURLResponseCSgs5Error_pSgtF
> - 580 20  libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x00007fff5158df22 $s10Foundation4DataVSgSo13NSURLResponseCSgs5Error_pSgIegggg_So6NSDataCSgAGSo7NSErrorCSgIeyByyy_TR
> - 162 21  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff22f5a4d0 CFNetwork + 38096 22  CFNetwork
>   0x00007fff22f6d740 _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseProxyURL + 17217 23
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff2592128c
>   **NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7 24  Foundation                          0x00007fff259211ad -[NSBlockOperation main] + 80 25  Foundation
>   0x00007fff259240dc **NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN** + 17 26
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff259203ee -[NSOperation
>   start] + 731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `s4Link22getPersistentContainerSo012NSPersistentD0CyF` contains some unreadable character

No it doesn't. This is standard Swift name mangling. Note that 4 is the length of "Link" and 22 is the length of "getPersistentContainer".

Comment: The specs are [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/Mangling.rst).